# Import Google Font using real url to font file

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

I use [GoogleFonts](https://fonts.google.com/) in my project and for some reason I can't import a font without using the 'embed' system.

For example if you want to import the `Titan One` font you can achieve it using:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titan+One&display=swap');

font-family: 'Titan One', cursive;
```

This url actually refers to a css file declaring the font:

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titan One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Titan One'), local('TitanOne'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/titanone/v7/mFTzWbsGxbbS_J5cQcjCmjgm-khyk-RW.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titan One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Titan One'), local('TitanOne'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/titanone/v7/mFTzWbsGxbbS_J5cQcjClDgm-khykw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

so I decide to skip the `@import` step to directly import the font from its static url (here: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/titanone/v7/mFTzWbsGxbbS_J5cQcjCmjgm-khyk-RW.woff2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Titan One';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/titanone/v7/mFTzWbsGxbbS_J5cQcjCmjgm-khyk-RW.woff2);
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Titan One';
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

But as you can see, the font does not apply to my title. Do you have any idea where the mistake is?

Comment: Open the Google CSS and copy the same : https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titan+One&display=swap. There is defined ranges and two font file used

Comment: It's pretty hard to say, what Google does behind the scenes. Why do you need it to import like that? Could you download the font and embed it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the `latin` file not the `latin-ext` but I recommend that you copy the whole Google file to make sure it works fine because the `unicode-range` is important

> The `unicode-range` CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters to be used from a font defined by @font-face and made available for use on the current page.
>
> The purpose of this descriptor is to allow the font resources to be segmented so that a browser only needs to download the font resource needed for the text content of a particular page. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)</sup>

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titan One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/titanone/v7/mFTzWbsGxbbS_J5cQcjClDgm-khykw.woff2);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Titan One';
}
```

```html
<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried with the `latin` after your comments and It's work. But have you an idea why? What's the difference between `latin` and `latin-ext`?

Comment: @johannchopin I added more details, it's all about the unicode-range

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, your refs and your work on SO ;)